# Component doesn't react on scope change from its controller

Tags: angularjs

I have two simple components which communicate using require. The problem is that variable changed in the function is not reflected in the component view. See the example below.

```html
<wizard-element data-active="true">First
      <wizard-test></wizard-test>
  </wizard-element>
  <wizard-element>Second
    <wizard-test></wizard-test>
  </wizard-element>
```

The components are simple and by clicking deactivate the wizard-element should be invisible, but it doesn't.

Wizard-element is a wrapper component responsible for showing and hiding. The wizard-test has buttons to show or hide and communicate with wizard-element by require.

```js
component('wizardElement',{
        transclude: true,
        controller: ['$scope',function($scope){

            this.activate = function(){
                console.log('show');
                this.active = true;
            }

            this.disactivate = function(){
                console.log('hide');
                $scope.active = false;
            }
        }],
        
        bindings: {
            'active': '=',
            'step': '<'
        },
        template: '<div ng-show="$ctrl.active" ng-transclude></div>'
})
.component('wizardTest',{
        controller: ['$scope',function($scope){

            this.activate =  function(){
              this.wizardElement.activate();
            }
            
            this.disactivate =  function(){
              this.wizardElement.disactivate();
            }
        }],
        require: {
          'wizardElement' : '^^wizardElement'    
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="$ctrl.activate()">Activate</button><button ng-click="$ctrl.disactivate()">Disactivate</button>'
});
```

Link to Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/A5Hl1qYDhaMTgvvuIS11?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `$scope` and `this` in your `activate()` and `disactivate()` functions.

try changing

```
this.disactivate = function() {
  console.log('hide');
  $scope.active = false;
}
```

To

```
this.disactivate = function() {
  console.log('hide');
  this.active = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Indeed, in my plunker example, it helped. Even though I built this example to reflect my app problem this doesn't work in my example as have no clue why

Answer (score 0):

Plunker example works after previous suggestion but my app doesn't even though it's as I think the same.  Methods *activate* and *disactivate* are invoked but doesn't change the view. I also dump {{$ctrl}} in the wizard-element template to see the scope, but the active value doesn't change.

```
<wizard>
    <wizard-element data-step="1" data-active="true" >First Step</wizard-element>
    <wizard-element data-step="2" >Second step</wizard-element>
    <button class="btn border-only center-block margin-top" wizard-next-control>Next</button>
```

And my JS:

```
    authApp.component('wizardElement',{
    transclude: true,
    controller: ['$scope','$timeout',function($scope,$timeout){

        this.active = this.active || false;

        this.$onInit = function() {
            this.wizardCtrl.addElement(this, this.step);
        }
        this.activate = function(){
            console.log('show', this.step);
            this.active = true;
        }

        this.disactivate = function(){
            console.log('hide', this.step);
            this.active = false;
        }
    }],
    require:{
        'wizardCtrl' : '^^wizard',
    },
    bindings: {
        'step': '<'
    },
    template: '<span>val:{{$ctrl}}</span><div ng-show="$ctrl.active"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>'});
```